# adding columns in pandas with different column names

Tags: pandas, dataframe, concatenation

hey guys pandas problem here, 4 data frames of the last 400 days of 4 different stocks, to be concatenated into one, they are in different indexes as the original pull for each stock from quandl starts with different start dates for the data.

each data frame looks similar to this:

```
          a       b       c       d      e
545  539.00  558.00  535.00  539.00   6.50
546  549.00  550.48  535.00  549.00  10.00
547  549.50  559.00  539.00  549.50   0.50
548  570.00  570.00  535.00  570.00  20.50
```

and this:

```
         g     h     i      j     k
461  4.480  4.62  4.45  4.480  0.02
462  4.420  4.55  4.42  4.420  0.05
```

My problem is that when I do

```
result = pd.concat([clin, avo, aph, abc], axis=1, ignore_index=True)
```

the result is:

```
  0   1   2   3   4      5     6     7      8     9      10     11     12  \
461  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  4.480  4.62  4.45  4.480  0.02    NaN    NaN    NaN   
462  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  4.420  4.55  4.42  4.420  0.05    NaN    NaN    NaN   
463  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  3.920  4.50  3.70  3.920  0.50    NaN    NaN    NaN   
464  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  3.920  3.95  3.90  3.920  0.00    NaN    NaN    NaN   
465  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  3.780  4.15  3.78  3.780  0.15    NaN    NaN
```

essentially the resulting data frame is not 400 rows with 20 features, I understand that this is because there would be Nan for the columns in other dataframes as the names are different, but Im confused as to how to join them regardless, I need it to be basicallly a very crude join on the end 
i tried `reset_index` but thinking about it now of course that wouldnt work because it doesnt create values for column a  in the other dataframes that do not have a column a

Comment: `ignore_index` ignores the label names, for `axis=1` it ignores the column names, if you want to just append column-wise then you could call `reset_index(drop=True)` on each df in the list

Comment: thanks for the reply man, but ive already done reset index for all four dataframes before, and then called concat with axis = 1 yet it still comes with 886 rows instead of 400

Comment: that shouldn't happen did you do something similar to my answer? Are you sure that the largest df is 400 rows?

Comment: yeah man the other answer called df.reset_index(drop=True) from within the concat function inside the brackets with each dataframe and that seems to have done the trick I dont know how thats different to calling the reset indux outside it but hey what works...works i guess

Comment: `reset_index` like most pandas functions returns a copy of the modified df so unless you did `df = df.reset_index(drop=True)` or `df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)` then you were operating on the original dfs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't care about the index then you could do:

```
In [7]:

pd.concat([df.reset_index(drop=True),df1.reset_index(drop=True)], axis=1)
Out[7]:
       a       b    c      d     e     g     h     i     j     k
0  539.0  558.00  535  539.0   6.5  4.48  4.62  4.45  4.48  0.02
1  549.0  550.48  535  549.0  10.0  4.42  4.55  4.42  4.42  0.05
2  549.5  559.00  539  549.5   0.5   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
3  570.0  570.00  535  570.0  20.5   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
```

Comment: this helped, got it there perfectly, although I did try this; I called each_dataframe.reset_index(drop = True) before I called the concat function, didnt work for somerea son